# In Path of War can Hidden Blades use a Strike or Boost Maneuver with a Counter Maneuver?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, path-of-war

In Path of War, can you use a Strike Maneuver with a Counter Maneuver?

For instance, can you initiate the strike *Rippling Current* ([Mithral Current](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/mithral-current-maneuvers/) 3; melee att +3d6 dmg; if quick drawn, make target flat-footed) as part of the attack of the counter *Mithral Flash* ([Mithral Current](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/mithral-current-maneuvers/) 5; opposed attack;   if quick drawn, can attack with +5d6 dmg) ?

Answer (score 5):

No. Please read the maneuvers. They indicate what kind of action they require—a counter requires an immediate, a boost requires a swift, and a strike requires a standard action. These cannot possibly be used at the same time. *At best*, the boost from your last turn may still affect you when you counter (but countering generally means you cannot boost in the next turn).

Stances, of course, apply continuously and so also apply when you use a counter.